# Synapse HTTPMethod

Tags: delphi, synapse

как получить исходный код из **HTTPMethod**('**GET**','ссылка кароч')

Это **синапс**

Answer (score 1):

я так делал

```
HttpGetText('http://вашсайт.нет', Memo1.Lines);
```

Но можно примеры в демках открыть. там есть такой код

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTP: THTTPSend;
begin
  HTTP := THTTPSend.Create;
  try
    HTTP.ProxyHost := Edit8.Text;
    HTTP.ProxyPort := Edit9.Text;
    HTTP.HTTPMethod('GET', Edit1.text);
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(HTTP.Headers);
    Memo2.Lines.LoadFromStream(HTTP.Document); // вот здесь текст переходит в мемо.
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Если нужно в строковою переменную, то проще использовать TStringList или TStringStream

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [THTTPSendEx](http://arhangelsoft.ru/delphi/advanced-synapse-library-thttpsendex/)